# Merging tags [images] and [image]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Both [images](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) and [image](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image) tags refer to the same thing and thus should be merged.

Qs tagged [images](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images)
Qs tagged [image](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been completed.

A tag synonym mapping `image` → `images` has been created.